# JSON Count the number of child and grandchild of each child

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json data and I want to get the number of children and grand children.

I have tried this but I can't get the number of grand children of each child:

**JSON**

```
var data = {  "members":[  
  {  
     "user_id":3961,
     "parent_id":3895,
     "first_name":"No",
     "last_name":"Ah",
     "avatar_url":null,
     "sub_members":[  
        {  
           "user_id":3965,
           "parent_id":3895,
           "first_name":"Uncle",
           "last_name":"Bear",
           "avatar_url":null,
           "sub_members":[  
              {  
                 "user_id":3957,
                 "parent_id":3956,
                 "first_name":"Child1",
                 "last_name":"Bear",
                 "avatar_url":null
              },
              {  
                 "user_id":3957,
                 "parent_id":3956,
                 "first_name":"Child2",
                 "last_name":"Bear",
                 "avatar_url":null
              },
              {  
                 "user_id":3957,
                 "parent_id":3956,
                 "first_name":"Child3",
                 "last_name":"Bear",
                 "avatar_url":null
              }
           ]
        }
     ]
  }]};
```

**JQUERY**

```
var count = 0;

  for ( property in data.members[0].sub_members ){
      if(data.members[0].sub_members.hasOwnProperty(property)){
          count++;
      }
  }
  console.log("total child  = " + count);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
 var total=0;
 var countChildren=function(data,num){
      if(data.sub_members&&data.sub_members.length){
         var len=data.sub_members.length;
         num+=len;
         for(var i=0;i<len;i++){
            countChildren(data.sub_members[i],num);
         }
      }
      return false;
 }
 countChildren(data.members,total);
```

Comment: After you exec the countChildren function, the result is already in the param total, you can print it any where.